# Django REST Framework browsable api filter controls not showing

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I followed the docs to add filtering to my API, installed django-filter, django-crispy-forms (added to INSTALLED_APPS) and using filter_backends/filter_fields/search_fields I can use the filtering using query parameters. However, the docs say: "Generic filters can also present themselves as HTML controls in the browsable API" and "the browsable API will present a filtering control for DjangoFilterBackend, like so:". My question is how? I don't see any additional controls for filtering/search. I'm using DRF 3.2.4.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Filters displaying as HTML controls on the browsable API is a feature of Django Rest Framework versions 3.3.0 and above.

http://www.django-rest-framework.org/topics/3.3-announcement/

It is unfortunate that they do not version their documentation.